# how to add a callback in boost::future in C++

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, future

I want to implement a feature that will call the callback function once the promise will set the value
of future.

I am using C++ boost 1.44  and I have tried below code, but it does not work as I expect to be,
Can somebody correct the program.

```
void callback_function()
{
     std::cout << "Final future  is ready" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::promise<std::string> promise;
    boost::unique_future<std::string> fut = promise.get_future();
    promise.set_wait_callback(boost::bind(Callback_function));
    promise.set_value("test");

    sleep(10);
}
```

So there are two questions here,

1. How to call callback_function immediately after the promise.set_value("test") in the above program.
2. Also I tried to pass parameter to callback function as below, But this fail to compile 
   saying no matching function to call to promise...

   ```
   void callback_function( boost::unique_future<std::string> & fut)
   {

    std::cout << "Final future  is ready with value" << fut.get() << std::endl;

   }

   int main()
   {
       boost::promise<std::string> promise;
       boost::unique_future<std::string> fut = promise.get_future();
       promise.set_wait_callback(boost::bind(Callback_function), boost::ref(fut));
       promise.set_value("test");
       sleep(10);
   }
   ```

**Added to the Question:**

For the purpose of posting code, I have added sleep in my main function, But I actually want to continue lots of other code processing in the main thread. So that main thread will not block on fut.get or fut.wait automatic callback should happens once promise will set the value. I have seen once such implementation in http://braddock.com/~braddock/future/current/ but this implementation is not a part of boost thread where they have provided add_callback functionality to future. I am looking something similar in the official boost 1.44 thread and future implementation. It is going to be very nice feature to have. Once again one point I want to say that promise may be set in some other thread.

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: We can find the reference code for boost future here, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/thread/future.hpp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for the promise to be ready, just call `wait()` (or one of the variants) on the future. That's what it's for.

The wait callback is there to *notify* the owner of the promise (or a "friend" :)) of the fact that somebody is waiting for the future:

```
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

void callback_function()
{
    std::cout << "Wait is called and promise not ready yet" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::promise<std::string> promise;
    boost::unique_future<std::string> fut = promise.get_future();
    promise.set_wait_callback(boost::bind(callback_function));

    boost::thread([&]{ sleep(2); promise.set_value("test"); });
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << fut.get();
}
```

This will print

```
Wait is called and promise not ready yet
test
```

(with 1 second before each line appearing). See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e91302ae3e3c810)**)

To answer question 2:

Now, if you do the bind as you describe, accessing the future again will just result in an infinite recursion: See it **[Crash On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61f1299c7632f455)**

---

**Update** To answer question 1.

> How to call callback_function immediately after the promise.set_value("test") in the above program

The simplest way would be:

```
promise.set_value("test");
callback_function();
```

Thought that might be too trivial. So, instead write:

```
boost::async([&]{ sleep(2); promise.set_value("test"); });

fut.wait(); // wait until promise is ready
callback_function(); // callback invocation
```

Comment: thank you  for the response, But as I mention it is boost 1.44 version. In which boost::async is not available.

Comment: What difference does that actually make?  set_wait_callback still doesn't do what you thought it did and the solutions are still the same.  Just use`thread` in the demo instead of async

Comment: Internally does it mean that async and thread both create a temp thread , do its task and go away. If that is the case that will be very good.

Comment: I've replaced `async` with `thread` in the example. The behaviours of [`boost::thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.callable_constructor), [`boost::async`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.async) and [`set_wait_callback`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.lazy_futures) are documented at the boost documentation site

Comment: so as I  understand callback that we set using promise.set_wait_callback will only get called when we have call the fut.get or fut.wait somewhere in our code before promise.set_value(). Is this a correct understanding. If this is true then the best way to callback is to just call a function after fut.wait as Sehe said. In this manner we wont involve any sleep in the code base. I am adding my new working code in the response .

Comment: Yes, the callback will only be called if the future is waited for before the promise is ready. This is mainly intended for "lazy" futures (i.e. futures that might not be evaluated at all). However, calling `fut.wait()` does do an implicite /sleep/ (as in the current thread is suspended until the promise is ready). This is far superior to calling sleep (as the synchronizatio is efficient and reliable). However, it's not wait free. (Look into Reactor style asynchrony (boost asio) or continuations (future::then, I believe in recent Boost Thread libraries))

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code for me that I h ave come up, 
I came up with this approach because of limitations on boost 1.44 like it does not have boost::async and the thread lambda was also not compiling with my gcc compiler

boost version : 1.44 
c++ compiler : gcc 4.3

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include "boost/thread/future.hpp"
#include "boost/bind.hpp"

void callback_test()
{
   std::cout << "callback_test" << std::endl;
}

void promise_task(boost::promise<std::string> & promise)
{
  std::cout << "promise_task" << std::endl;
//  sleep (2);
  promise.set_value("PROMISE");

}

void future_task(boost::unique_future<std::string> & future)
{
  std::cout << "futute_task" << std::endl;
  std::cout << future.get() << std::endl;
  callback_test();

}
void promise_and_future_task(
     boost::promise<std::string> & promise,
     boost::unique_future<std::string> & future)
{
  boost::thread promise_task_(&promise_task,
        boost::ref(promise));

  boost::thread future_task_(&future_task,
        boost::ref(future));
}

void do_other_main_task()
{
  sleep(5);
}

int main()
{
  boost::promise<std::string> promise;
  boost::unique_future<std::string> fut = promise.get_future();
//  promise.set_wait_callback(boost::bind(callback_test));
  boost::thread task(
      &promise_and_future_task,
      boost::ref(promise),
      boost::ref(fut));

  std::cout << "MAIN THREAD" << std::endl;

  do_other_main_task();
  return 0;
}
```